# Why is an empty list being exported here? I want the appended list to be exported

Tags: node.js, express

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Post = require("/home/chibbaa/5chin/models/post.js");


const messageList = [];

Post.find()
    .then((res)=>{
        res.forEach((post)=>{
        messageList.push(post);
        }).then((res)=>{
            module.exports = messageList;
        })
        /*console.log(messageList);
        module.exports = messageList; */
    })
```

```
const messageList = require('/home/chibbaa/5chin/static/messages.js');
router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    
    res.render('home', {messageList});
})
```

Why does an empty list get passed on to the render function in the second piece of code?

Comment: What is the file above exporting? e.g. module.exports

Comment: You are confused by synchron/asynchron code execution. There are hunderts of this kind of posts here.

Comment: Basically, i'm getting the collections of posts from my external DB and pushing each one of them into an array (messageList) and then exporting the list.